# Rundeck filter for selecting a default value

Tags: rundeck

Is there any way to select one default value from ten host name. For example I have tagged ten hosts. In my filter I want these 10 hosts but default when I execute only one will be selected.

- host1 --> by default this should be mark as ticked when I execute and others should be there
  but not marked
- host2
- host3
- host4

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it´s possible, also I made a job definition example to [test it](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/creating-jobs.html#importing-job-definitions).

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 37179ac6-9b7d-403d-8d31-f260ad9b5928
  loglevel: INFO
  name: DefaultOptionDemo
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  nodefilters:
    dispatch:
      excludePrecedence: true
      keepgoing: false
      rankOrder: ascending
      successOnEmptyNodeFilter: false
      threadcount: '1'
    filter: ${option.mynode}
  nodesSelectedByDefault: true
  options:
  - enforced: true
    name: mynode
    value: node01
    values:
    - node00
    - node01
    - node02
    valuesListDelimiter: ','
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - exec: whoami
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 37179ac6-9b7d-403d-8d31-f260ad9b5928
```

1. Create a job, give it a name, and go to the Workflow tab.
2. Add a new option a give it a name (`mynode` in the example).
3. On the "Allowed values" section put the list of available hosts separated by commas e.g: `node00,node01,node01`. [Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ty7BL.jpg).
4. Put your default value in the "Default value" section e.g: `node01`. [Take a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpfGR.jpg).
5. Select "Enforced from Allowed Values" in "Restrictions" section and then save the option. [Check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ty7BL.jpg).
6. Add a new step, in the example, I put the `whoami` command. Save the step.
7. Go to the Nodes tab, click on the "Dispatch to Nodes" radio button, and put the option on the "Node Filter" textbox, e.g: `${option.mynode}`. [Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrDDd.jpg).

Now [you can select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hc0My.jpg) any node from your list where the default node is "node01". [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxg9B.jpg).